# How can I send multiple checkbox values to firebase in swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem to send multiple checkbox values to Firebase in Swift 
I want to send values of 7 checkboxs (7 Days of the Week) to Realtime Database. if which one is select send true to firebase. if not select send notthing or false to firebase.

I knowhow to read and write data to firebase but i'm not sure But I don't know how to do this.

I'm using pod AIFlatSwitch to make chekckbox animation

```
@IBOutlet weak var bgM: AIFlatSwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var bgT: AIFlatSwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var bgW: AIFlatSwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var bgTh: AIFlatSwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var bgF: AIFlatSwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var bgSat: AIFlatSwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var bgSun: AIFlatSwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let action1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.callActionEveryDay (_:)))
    self.bgeveryDay.addGestureRecognizer(action1)

    let action2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.callActionM (_:)))
    self.bgM.addGestureRecognizer(action2)

    let action3 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.callActionT (_:)))
    self.bgT.addGestureRecognizer(action3)

    let action4 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.callActionW (_:)))
    self.bgW.addGestureRecognizer(action4)

    let action5 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.callActionTh (_:)))
    self.bgTh.addGestureRecognizer(action5)

    let action6 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.callActionF (_:)))
    self.bgF.addGestureRecognizer(action6)

    let action7 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.callActionSat (_:)))
    self.bgSat.addGestureRecognizer(action7)

    let action8 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.callActionSun (_:)))
    self.bgSun.addGestureRecognizer(action8)

}

//Action when click on each view

@objc func callActionM(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if bgM.isSelected == false {
        bgM.isSelected = true
        bgM.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 75.0 / 255.0, green: 182.0 / 255.0, blue: 71.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        mLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    }else{
        bgM.isSelected = false
        bgM.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        mLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
@objc func callActionT(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if bgT.isSelected == false {
        bgT.isSelected = true
        bgT.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 75.0 / 255.0, green: 182.0 / 255.0, blue: 71.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        tLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    }else{
        bgT.isSelected = false
        bgT.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        tLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
@objc func callActionW(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if bgW.isSelected == false {
        bgW.isSelected = true
        bgW.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 75.0 / 255.0, green: 182.0 / 255.0, blue: 71.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        wLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    }else{
        bgW.isSelected = false
        bgW.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        wLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
@objc func callActionTh(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if bgTh.isSelected == false {
        bgTh.isSelected = true
        bgTh.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 75.0 / 255.0, green: 182.0 / 255.0, blue: 71.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        thLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    }else{
        bgTh.isSelected = false
        bgTh.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        thLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
@objc func callActionF(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if bgF.isSelected == false {
        bgF.isSelected = true
        bgF.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 75.0 / 255.0, green: 182.0 / 255.0, blue: 71.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        fLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    }else{
        bgF.isSelected = false
        bgF.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        fLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
@objc func callActionSat(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if bgSat.isSelected == false {
        bgSat.isSelected = true
        bgSat.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 75.0 / 255.0, green: 182.0 / 255.0, blue: 71.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        satLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    }else{
        bgSat.isSelected = false
        bgSat.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        satLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
@objc func callActionSun(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if bgSun.isSelected == false {
        bgSun.isSelected = true
        bgSun.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 75.0 / 255.0, green: 182.0 / 255.0, blue: 71.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        sunLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    }else{
        bgSun.isSelected = false
        bgSun.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        sunLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you send the values?

Comment: can you teach me how to send the values

Comment: Can i send it like this @RomanPodymov

func whichOneIsSelected() {
        
        if bgM.isSelected == true {
            workdays = ["Monday":true]
        }
    }

Comment: I cannot see the code that you use to communicate with Firebase. Could you please add it?

Comment: Your code doesn't show any interaction with Firebase yet. If you don't know how to do that yet, I recommend checking out the Firebase documentation for [reading and writing to the database from iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write), as it likely does a better job explaining than we can do here. If you've tried something and can't get it to work, edit your question to include the [**minimum** code that reproduces what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).